# Transfer file to physical iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have set up a provisioning profile to debug my app (through Xcode) on a connected physical device.

The problem is this app requires certain supporting files. With the simulators on Mac, I simply navigate to the `Documents` directory for the app under the simulator directory and place the files there.

Is there a way to get these same files on to the physical device?

Comment: Can't you just make them part of the target's resources? Then, you can load them at runtime using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:]`.

Comment: For certain things I could but this is more so for files that are not part of the program itself, and therefore shouldn't be part of the bundle. Think iTunes and downloaded songs.

Comment: Hmm, I remember you can **extract** files from the `Documents` folder using iTunes (if your app's settings allow for it), but not sure if you can _put in_.

Comment: If, in real life, they're gonna be files that your app downloads form a remote server, perhaps you should implement that functionality first (i.e., a dummy server).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the files within your project files structure.
So they are copied to your App Bundle and will be available through the documents directory.

To add files to your iOS Project correctly:

1. Right click on the project icon at the top of the file list on the left.
2. Select `Add files to <YourProjectName>`
3. Select the folder/file you want to include and click Add.

   - Don't forget to select the correct `target` by selecting it from the given list. Refer to the screenshot please.
4. If your resource is not a single file but directory structure and you want all the directory tree copied, then remember to select the **Added folders: Create groups**

The files adding pop up window would seem like the following in XCode 6.x:
[image]

When the target is built, open up the bundle and your directory structure will exist inside fully intact. Not only that, these files may be accessible through iOS SDK as following.

So you may have to copy them to documents/library directory within the App as you may want to access them within the app.

Use the following code to do copy them.

```
// Check if the file has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
BOOL success;
NSString *fileName = @"test.jpg";
NSString *LIBRARY_DIR_PATH = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [LIBRARY_DIR_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSLog(@"%@",filePath);

// Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
// of the file and to copy it over if required
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// Check if the file has already been created in the users filesystem
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

// If the file already exists then return without doing anything
if(success) return;

// Else,
NSLog(@"FILE WASN'T THERE! SO GONNA COPY IT!");

// then proceed to copy the file from the application to the users filesystem
// Get the path to the files in the application package
NSString *filePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

// Copy the file from the package to the users filesystem
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:filePathFromApp toPath:filePath error:nil];
```

Hope the above code sample is clear for you.

So whenever you want to access that file within your App, you can get reference to that file by getting it's path as follows:

```
    NSString *sqliteDB = [LIBRARY_DIR_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

**Note:** In any case if you require the files to be copied to the `Documents` directory within users app installed location, Replace the `LIBRARY_DIR_PATH` with the following:

```
NSString *DOCUMENTS_DIR_PATH = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this answer is helpful to you!

Cheers!

Comment: This is a great solution. A minor detail: I think he wants it into `Documents`, not `Library`.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Actually that might have to be aligned with apple guidelines right? else it will be a problem later on.

Comment: @NicolasMiari done! :-) given the code snippet to get reference to the `Documents` directory too.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this and see how it goes. Seems like it does what I want.

Comment: @Ash sure! :-) Hope it will provide the correct solution for your problem! Let me know what happened.

Comment: @KasunRandika true; must be careful what you store in Documents, unless you flag it with "no backup".

Comment: @Kasun Worked like a charm! Had to make a few minor alterations to fit my intended workflow but yea, the idea was perfect. There should be a book called "Hacker's guide to Apple policies" and this should definitely be in it :)

Comment: :-) yes, true that. Actually please concern whether you need to copy the required files to `Library` or to `Documents` folders. Hope as @NicolasMiari told, it should be into `Documents`. Cheers!

Comment: @Kasun Library is fine. I can go with that. The 'hack' implication was directed towards Apple policies such as the one here which prevents straightforward copying of files to your app's directory on a physical device...even though the provisioning profile states that the app belongs to you....and you should be able to do whatever you want.